# <s:select> Error:The requested list key 'typeSurvey' could not be resolved

Tags: jsp, struts2

this is my jsp:

```
<s:form action="InsertSurvey">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> ID Survey: </td><td><s:textfield name="SurveyValues.survey.idtextsurvey"/> </td>
                <td> Tipo Survey: </td><td><s:select list="typeSurvey"/> </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </s:form>
```

and this is my action without get/set

```
public class InsertSurveyAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

protected SurveyValues surveyValues;
protected List typeSurvey;
protected String typeSurveySelected;

public InsertSurveyAction() {

}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
  return SUCCESS;
}

public void prepare() throws Exception {
    typeSurvey = new ArrayList();
    typeSurvey.add("Multi");
    typeSurvey.add("Singolo");
}
```

Why I have this problem?
*

> tag 'select', field 'list': The
>   requested list key 'typeSurvey' could
>   not be resolved as a
>   collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator
>   type. Example: people or people.{name}
>   - [unknown location]

I have the last version of struts2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the tag <s:form action="InsertSurvey">
only runs on explicitly for example after a submit, in your case the action was not executed and therefore typeSurvey values are not available.

Answer (score 0):

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />



<package name="default"  extends="struts-default">

    <action name="InsertSurvey" class="it.survey.actions.InsertSurveyAction">
        <result name="success">/InsertSurvey_step1.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you did not declare a getter for the typeSurvey List,
try with 
`public List<String> getTypeSurvey() {
  return typeSurvey;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to reach the jsp page(directly accessing the jsp page) without traversing any action hence not  initializing your list in the process.so try to initialize the list in prepare method of the action.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

just define the Getter and Setter of the  List typeSurvey

and create object of typeSurvey and also add the item in list inside the constructor not in prepare method.

Comment: I've tried init-ing the list inside the constructor, ALSO while declaring it in the instance var area. Still not luck! :(